# FB Login using Swift 3 not returning any values and not get back the user to the App after successful login

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-ios-sdk, swift3, ios10

I'm using `iOS 10` `Swift 3` to integrate `FB Login`. I have followed all steps from `Facebook` documentation. Now the issue is, after successful login it doesn't returning any values and not get back the user to the app.

Note: The same works perfectly in `Swift 2`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Hi I raised this issue to facebook developer support and the issue is that I have not implemented the correct delegate methods for iOS10. and you can find the correct delegate implementation [here](https://gist.github.com/codegefluester/f797dd723e93e545b855525a4b9ab057)

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


public func application(_ application: UIApplication,  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
// Override point for customization after application launch.

return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
}

 public func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(
  app,
  open: url as URL!,
  sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String,
  annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation]
)
}

public func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(
  application,
  open: url as URL!,
  sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
  annotation: annotation)
}
}
```

Comment: Is your last function part of the AppDelegate? I wanted to use it.. but it doesn't autocomplete for me. The `application(_:open:sourceApplication:annotation)` one.

Answer (score 4):

Don't forget to set Keychain Sharing 
project targets -> Capabilities -> Keychain Sharing -> Toggle Switch ON

[image: Keychain Sharing status]

you can follow this 
http://ashishkakkad.com/2015/05/facebook-login-swift-language-ios/

Answer (score 3):

for me the "FBSDKApplicationDelegate" doesn't work for the latest Facebook Swift SDK version v0.2.0

You can find my implementation for v0.2.2 here: https://gist.github.com/mbecker/bdbd28cd11394085c01cf442aaa42c72

```
//
//  AppDelegate.swift
//
//  Created by Mats Becker on 9/25/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 safari.digital. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import FacebookCore

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        return SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.

        // Call the 'activate' method to log an app event for use
        // in analytics and advertising reporting.
        AppEventsLogger.activate(application)
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }

    public func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

        return SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(
            app,
            open: url as URL!,
            sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String,
            annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation]
        )
    }

    public func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
        return SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(
            application,
            open: url as URL!,
            sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
            annotation: annotation
        )
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Evn: iOS 10, XCode 8.3.2, Swift 3, facebook-sdk-swift-0.2.0
Tested and worked.

Since above answers are indicated as deprecated code, I have changed the syntax.

https://gist.github.com/jgchoi/097b59d85d6b378a81925be93a62fef9

```
import UIKit
import FacebookCore

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

  var window: UIWindow?


  public func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

     return SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }

    public func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    return SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(app, open: url, options: options)
  }

  public func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    return SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, open: url)
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**I have experienced the same problem with Facebook and Twitter integration.I have solved it as follows.**

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

    let appname:String = options.first?.value as! String
    print(appname)
    if appname == "com.facebook.Facebook" {
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(
            app,
            open: url as URL!,
            sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String,
            annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation]
        )
    }
    return Twitter.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, options: options)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    return SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(app, open: url, options: options)
  }
```

Add this in addition to what you have in AppDelegate

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the below code didn't work for me

```
public func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    return SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, open: url)
}
```

So had to change it to

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    let options = [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication: sourceApplication as Any,
                   UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.annotation: annotation]
    return SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, open: url, options: options)
}
```