# Facebook login not working in swift

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

Im trying to implement Facebook login in my app but when I try to login it goes to Facebook app and comes back to my game but the login button doesn't become log out and if I try to get any information such as access token, granted permissions or declined permissions it is nil. this is the code I have:

```
import Foundation
class IntroScene: SKScene, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {
let loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton = {
    let button = FBSDKLoginButton()
    button.readPermissions = ["email"]
    return button
}()

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

    view.addSubview(loginButton)
    loginButton.center = (self.view?.center)!
    loginButton.delegate = self
}

func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {

}

func loginButtonWillLogin(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {
    if(error == nil)
    {
        print("login complete")
        //print(FBSDKAccessToken.current()) -> crashes because its nil
        //print(result.grantedPermissions) -> crashes its nil
    }
    else{
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
}
```

my info.plist looks like following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fbapi</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
        <string>fbauth2</string>
        <string>fbshareextension</string>
    </array>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>facebook.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
            <key>fbcdn.net</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
            <key>akamaihd.net</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
            <string>//fbmyid</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>//myid</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>Crazy Traffic Saga</string>
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>en</string>
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
<string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
<key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
<string>6.0</string>
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
<key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
<string>APPL</string>
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>1.0</string>
<key>CFBundleSignature</key>
<string>????</string>
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>1</string>
<key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
<true/>
<key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
<string>LaunchScreen</string>
<key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
<string>Main</string>
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
<array>
    <string>armv7</string>
</array>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
```

Comment: which swift version you use ?

Comment: Not well enough to give you an entire solution, so here's it. Give it a try, https://edbinx.com/apple/ios/use-facebook-fbsdk-swift-cocoapods-ios-9-13369.html

Comment: Im using Swift 3 @HimanshuMoradiya

Comment: I'm doing basically the first part of this tutorial and can't get it to work @Fennec

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to this post: [FB Login using Swift 3 not returning any values and not get back the user to the App after successful login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39632635/fb-login-using-swift-3-not-returning-any-values-and-not-get-back-the-user-to-the)
I found the problem. There is one more function that should be added to App Delegate. 
Here is how I got Facebook login working

- Download SDK and add to project
- Set up info.plist according to Facebook website
- In app delegate added:

  ```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
  // Override point for customization after application launch.
  FIRApp.configure()
  FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

  return true
  }

  public func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

      return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(
          app,
          open: url as URL!,
          sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String,
      annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation]
  )
  }

  public func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL,     sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
          return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(
              application,
              open: url as URL!,
              sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
              annotation: annotation)
  }
  ```
- In the SKScene I'm showing the button (could be in a view controller as well):

  ```
  class IntroScene: SKScene, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {
      override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
          self.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
          let loginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
          loginButton.center = (self.view?.center)!
          self.view?.addSubview(loginButton)
          loginButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 360, height: 60) // makes it bigger
          loginButton.center = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY + 90)
          loginButton.delegate = self
          loginButton.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email"]
          if let _ = FBSDKAccessToken.current(){
              //already logged in 
              fetchProfile()
          }
      }
      func fetchProfile() {
      let parameters = ["fields": "first_name, email, last_name, picture"]

      FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: parameters).start(completionHandler: { (connection, user, requestError) -> Void in

          if requestError != nil {
              print("----------ERROR-----------")
              print(requestError)
              return
          }
          let userData = user as! NSDictionary
          let email = userData["email"] as? String
          let firstName = userData["first_name"] as? String
          let lastName = userData["last_name"] as? String
          var pictureUrl = ""
          if let picture = userData["picture"] as? NSDictionary, let data = picture["data"] as? NSDictionary, let url = data["url"] as? String {
              pictureUrl = url
              print(pictureUrl)
          }
       })
       }

  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Put this code in your AppDelegate.swift

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
      return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
 }



func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication:  sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
```

Check FacebookAccessToken in your Facebook Button Click ViewController.

```
if FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil {
            FBSDKLoginManager().logOut()
            return
}

let login:FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
login.logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], handler: { (result:FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
     if(error != nil){
            FBSDKLoginManager().logOut()
     }else if(result.isCancelled){
            FBSDKLoginManager().logOut()
     }else{
                //Handle login success
            self.returnUserData()
        }
 })
```

Get Response of FacebookData.

```
func returnUserData()
{
  let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "email"])
  graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
      if ((error) != nil)
      {
            // Process error
            print("Error: \(error)")
       }
       else
       {
            print(result)

        }
    })
}
```

Comment: I have the App Delegate code already (sorry I forgot to include in the question). For the middle part where exactly should I put the code? Do I need a View Controller or can I use the SKScene Im using? and where should I put it? viewDidLoad?  also I get this error when I try adding it Cannot convert value of type '(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, NSError!) -> Void' to expected argument type 'FBSDKLoginManagerRequestTokenHandler!'

Comment: @toiavalle i don't use swift 3.0 i am using swift 2.0 so is their possible from your side then convert this code for work fine in swift 3.0. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Now Facebook offers Swift sdk for your iOS app. 
[Swift sdk for Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift/getting-started)

Check that out, and Have fun

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to set Keychain Sharing project targets -> Capabilities -> Keychain Sharing -> Toggle Switch ON 
[Keychain Sharing status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7pLm.png)

you can follow this http://ashishkakkad.com/2015/05/facebook-login-swift-language-ios/